# Widgets reverting to English after reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, widget

When I set my iOS app’s language to Spanish for example, then when I reboot my phone, my home and Lock Screen widgets revert back to the default English localization. If I open the app it’s still set to Spanish; only the home and Lock Screen widgets revert back to English.

The only way to get it back to Spanish is by going to my app’s setting, and setting the preferred language to English then Spanish again.